# Magento 2 - Factory Related Question

Tags: magento2, factory, interface

I have created a custom module, in that I have created the interface.

As I am learning magento, I have seen in demo videos that for ex:-

This is my custom interface name `AffiliateMemberInterface`.

Now when I am injecting it into plugin, I have to use it as `AffiliateMemberFactory`.

So my question is, how I can get an idea that when i have to add "Factory" word with my interface name during use.

I am getting confused in it. So if anyone can help me out with this confusion then it will be good for me.

Thanks

Comment: It is not the interface, do you have model file "AffiliateMember" ?

Comment: Yes, i have model file with same name but i have same name interface also.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `./generated` folder

It's as simple as that.

Search the folder for `AffiliateMemberFactory` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: do you know about this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295306/77631

Comment: Thanks for your response. will check this above things.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to Interface, You can create factory method for Model.

You do not need to explicitly define them because they are an automatically generated class type.

When you reference a factory in a class constructor, Magento’s object manager generates the factory class if it does not exist.

You can read more about factories [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, will check it.