# Element 'block', attribute 'templates': The attribute 'templates' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.3.3

am facing this issue from past two hours, i have tried to add a custom module and this problem arise. now i have removed the module but the error still persist

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'templates': The attribute 'templates' is not allowed.
Line: 749


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'templates': The attribute 'templates' is not allowed.
Line: 749

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000004229483d0000000026c1125f#, array(), NULL, 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000004229483d0000000026c1125f#, array(), NULL, 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', '%message%\nLine: ...')) called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000004229483d0000000026c1125f#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000004229483d0000000026c1125f#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Config\DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => 'E:/xampp/htdocs/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000004229483d0000000026c1125f#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:xs...', 'layout_merged', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php:494]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend_...', '<!--\r\n    <refer...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php:470]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(array()) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:253]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:875]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [vendor\magento\module-cms\Helper\Page.php:171]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(&Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000042294b600000000026c1125f#, 'home') called at [vendor\magento\module-cms\Controller\Index\Index.php:74]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL) called at [generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php:108]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor.php:39]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:159]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#, &Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#0000000042294b600000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:99]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#27 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000004229488a0000000026c1125f#, &Closure#00000000422948e80000000026c1125f#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#29 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000004229488a0000000026c1125f#, &Closure#00000000422948e80000000026c1125f#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#), NULL) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php:26]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004229492d0000000026c1125f#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:137]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:261]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000422949530000000026c1125f#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

still looking for a solution but no success yet between am perfectly able to use my admin panel but am facing issue at the store front-end
thanks in advance

Comment: Where you are getting this error ?

Comment: at the time of loading customer view

Comment: In backend or frontend ?

Comment: Can you please let me know your exact URL ?

Comment: actually am running it locally using apache

Comment: Yes, But can you please let me know what is your URL exclude your base url. like.. **www.example.com/test/index/index** or **localhost/test/index/index**

Comment: http://localhost:96/magento2.3.3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100921/discussion-between-pramod-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: Guyzz for ryt now i have fixed this issue but still i dont have any proper fix for this issue and dont how this arises

Comment: @KishanSavaliya do you know about this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295306/77631